# MySQL Slow double join

Tags: mysql, performance, join, indexing

I have a Link table with `from_uid` and `to_uid` (both indexed) and I want to filter out certain ids. So I do:

```
SELECT l.uid
  FROM Link l 
  JOIN filter_ids t1 ON l.from_uid = t1.id 
  JOIN filter_ids t2 ON l.to_uid   = t2.id
```

Now for some reason this is unexpectedly slow :( whereas each individual join is very fast. Can it not use the index right?

`EXPLAIN` tells me:

```
id  select  table type  possible_keys   key      key_len ref  rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE  t1    index Null            PRIMARY  34      Null 12205 Using index
1   SIMPLE  l     ref   from_uid,to_uid from_uid 96      func 6     Using where
1   SIMPLE  t2    index Null            PRIMARY  34      Null 12205 Using where; Using index; Using join buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea if it'll help but try:

```
select l.uid
from Link l
where l.from_uid in (select id from filter_ids)
and l.to_uid in (select id from filter_ids)
```

Maybe it'll make better work with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The EXPLAIN tells you that the JOIN actually starts from the `t1` table. That is you need to add a new index on `Link` (or better extend the current `from_uid` index):

```
(from_uid, to_uid, uid)
```

or if `uid` is the primary key, just:

```
(from_uid, to_uid)
```

**UPD**
What you are describing is strange. You can try running just:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN l.uid
FROM Link l 
JOIN filter_ids t1 ON l.from_uid = t1.id 
JOIN filter_ids t2 ON l.to_uid   = t2.id
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but I can tell that to the people owning that table. Is there technically a way to force mysql do it right/faster without modifying the table?

Comment: @Gerenuk, well, in reality, you should adapt the database to your queries and not the queries the database. If the query is not that important though, you should accept that it can be inefficient.

Comment: Well, as I said, in reality I cannot modify the Link table by will. The question was if it is possible to do in in one query, since a split query is very fast. Btw, for some reason your suggested index makes the query even slower... :(

Comment: I get almost 50000 result rows in about 4sec if I do a two step query with from_uid JOIN, ADD INDEX, to_uid JOIN. I believe in the above form it took about 40sec, but I don't dare to try again since the admins complain :)

Comment: Hmm thanks for the suggestion. It didnt work though :( After 2min it still hadn't stopped and EXPLAIN said no index is being used to Link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6849/discussion-between-newtover-and-gerenuk)